# Algorithm Complexity - Big O notation

Tags: time-complexity

I was trying to analyze an algorithm complexity here and I got stuck

Could you please help me out?

The algorithm is

```
for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    for(let j = 1; j <= i; j++){
        Operation with O(n) complexity...
    }
}
```

At first, I thought it would be O(n³) but something tells me it might as well be some log function.

Answer (score 0):

`j` goes from 1 to 1, then from 1 to 2, then... from 1 to n.

So that makes 1+2+...+n, or n(n+1)/2, or O(n^2)

If all of these perform an O(n), you get a total of O(n^3)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++){ // this runs for n times
    for(let j = 1; j <= i; j++){ // this runs up to i, i depends on n, it will go through 1, 2, 3, ... up to n times
    // the formula for this sum is n(n+1)/2, since we are applying the formula for the
    // summation, we are already including the outer loop
        Operation with O(n) complexity... // this is again O(n)
    }
}
```

Putting it all together we get:

```
[ [n * ( n + 1 )] / 2 ] * n
```

this simplifies to `O(n^3)`

Answer (score 0):

For loop for given n elements has a complexity of O(n). Two nested for loops O(n^2), so in this case two for loops and O(n) operation sums up to O(n*n*n) = O(n^3).